# Golang multidimensional slice copy

Tags: go, multidimensional-array, slice

I was trying to make a clone of multidimensional slice, because when I have changed elements in the duplicated slice, the elements in the original one were overwritten also.

The only method that worked for me was:

```
duplicate := make([][]int, len(matrix))
for i := 0; i < len(matrix); i++ {
    duplicate[i] = make([]int, len(matrix[0]))
    for j := 0; j < len(matrix[0]); j++ {
        duplicate[i][j] = matrix[i][j]
    }
}
```

is there any other way - shorter or more efficient to achieve the same result? thanks

Comment: You can eliminate the inner for loop using https://golang.org/pkg/builtin/#copy but I'm not sure if it is more efficient or not. I'd guess that a builtin would be.

Comment: thanks, working ;) at least less to write

Comment: I may benchmark it later too as I am curious to see how it compares.

Comment: looking forward for your benchmark ;) would be nice if you can give me a hint how can I benchmark by myself...thanks

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use copy for the inner loop (which should be more efficient) and range for the outer loop (which results in nicer code).

Result:

```
duplicate := make([][]int, len(matrix))
for i := range matrix {
    duplicate[i] = make([]int, len(matrix[i]))
    copy(duplicate[i], matrix[i])
}
```

---

If your goal is efficiency, it may make sense to do more allocation up front. This doesn't lead to more readable code but will lead to more efficient code if you are doing this often. This code assumes you have at least one row and that all rows are of the same length. You will need to add tests for that.

```
n := len(matrix)
m := len(matrix[0])
duplicate := make([][]int, n)
data := make([]int, n*m)
for i := range matrix {
    start := i*m
    end := start + m
    duplicate[i] = data[start:end:end]
    copy(duplicate[i], matrix[i])
}
```

Depending on what you are doing, it may make sense to make a "matrix type" that is implemented using only a single slice. A slice of slices is not the most efficient data structure, even if it is simpler to work with.

---

Before deciding if you need to be efficient, make sure that you are spending a lot of time doing copying using profiling. Then, after you have determined this is in fact a hotspot, start running benchmarks. See https://golang.org/pkg/testing/#hdr-Benchmarks for details.

Comment: Hah, if I'd known I'd get that much easy rep, I'd have done a full answer myself. Kudos though because this really is a very good answer.

Comment: BTW, a warning comment on using a single slice. If you happen to ever be modifying the `x` or `y` length of the matrix, it is a bad idea to try using a flat matrix.

Comment: Good point, just fixed that by adding a cap. Still, it means that any of those slices can prevent the entire thing from being garbage collected. While that leads to less work for the collector, it can also lead to inaccessible data not being collected.

Answer (score -1):

You could roundtrip it through gob:

```
package main

import (
   "bytes"
   "encoding/gob"
   "fmt"
)

func sliceCopy(in, out interface{}) {
   buf := new(bytes.Buffer)
   gob.NewEncoder(buf).Encode(in)
   gob.NewDecoder(buf).Decode(out)
}

func main() {
   a := [][]int{
      {1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9},
   }
   var b [][]int
   sliceCopy(a, &b)
   fmt.Println(b)
}
```

https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/gob

Comment: A good solution to duplicate arbitrary data but highly inefficient for this simple case.